# ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected (Retrieve department wise highest 2 salaries)

Tags: sql, oracle12c

I was trying to retrieve the highest two salaries by each department. But I am getting error! Please help, I will be appreciated, Thanks.

```
CREATE TABLE emp_h (    Dept varchar(100),  Emp varchar(100),   Sal numeric(18,2) )
```

Values are inserted in this table below.

```
SELECT * FROM emp_h

    DEPT    EMP SAL
    Comp    A   6000
    Comp    B   7000
    Comp    C   10000
    Comp    D   9000
    Elec    P   2000
    Elec    Q   10000
    Elec    R   11000
    Eng     AA  15000
    Eng     BB  2000
    Eng     BB  7000
    Eng     BB  3000
```

I want the output (Department wise top 2 highest salary)

```
Dept    Emp Sal
----------------------------
Comp    C   10000
Comp    D   9000
Elec    R   11000
Elec    Q   10000
Eng     AA  15000
Eng     BB  7000
```

Now I ran this query to retrieve the highest 2 salary each department wise:

```
SELECT * FROM(SELECT RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY DEPT ORDER BY SAL DESC) AS 'Rank', * FROM emp_h) AS A WHERE RANK <= 2
```

**Result:**

```
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 25 Column: 61
```

Comment: are you sure you can use `*` after the `rank()...` function?

Comment: I think so. Please correct my errors.

Comment: if you remove the `,*` does it work? If that works, then try using `*,` before the `Rank` column. If that doesn't then you'll need to explicitly refer to the columns in emp_h.

Comment: No. It's not working. I think I need to think any other procedure to write the query :(

Comment: @cowbert - the `*` works anywhere in the SELECT list, but it must be qualified unless it is the **only** item in the list.

Answer (score -1):

Oracle likes you to qualify `*` if  there are any other columns on the row.  So try this:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM (SELECT RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY DEPT ORDER BY SAL DESC) AS rnk, e.* 
      FROM emp_h e
      ) e
WHERE rnk <= 2;
```

Comment: Sorry! This is the result I am getting:

`ORA-00904: "E": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 31 Column: 3`

Comment: you're looking for `emp_h.*` here

Comment: Sorry! I ran using `emp_h.*` But here is the result

`ORA-00904: "EMP_H": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 30 Column: 78`

Comment: `SELECT * FROM emp_h`


--------------------------------
    `DEPT    EMP SAL
    Comp    A   6000
    Comp    B   7000
    Comp    C   10000
    Comp    D   9000
    Elec    P   2000
    Elec    Q   10000
    Elec    R   11000
    Eng     AA  15000
    Eng     BB  2000
    Eng     BB  7000
    Eng     BB  3000`